# PHP reloading content

Tags: php

I am trying to live update content on the page then the user clicks buttons.

content section:

```
<p class="chapterContent"><?php echo $chapterContent[$chapter]; ?></p>
```

Here are my buttons:

```
<span class="navigationItem"><a href="" onclick= <?php $chapter = 0; ?>>1</a></span>  
<span class="navigationItem"><a href="" onclick= <?php $chapter = 1; ?>>2</a></span>
```

$chapterContent is an array with different strings. So then user clicks on 1 it loads $chapterContent[0] if he clicks 2 it loads $chapterContent[1]
What I have does not work and how can I do it that the html code in class .chapterContent reloads with correct chapter? Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need to look at [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) to achieve that.

Comment: jQuery or any other AJAX methodology. Don't ignore http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: can you show your full code & what is the error

Answer (score 2):

What you needs is something like this!

```
<p id="chapterContent"></p>

<span class="navigationItem"><a href="" onclick="return display_text('0');">1</a></span>  
<span class="navigationItem"><a href="" onclick="return display_text('1');">2</a></span>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--

function display_text( which )
{
    $.post( "display.php", { which : which }, function( data ){ document.getElementById( "chapterContent" ).innerHTML = html =  data }, "html" );

    return false;
}

//-->
</script>
```

put this inside the display.php file:

```
<?php echo $chapterContent[$_POST["which"]]; ?>
```

You should of course add code that adds security etc!